# A spring integration test

Tags: java, spring

In my integration test, I tried to use resttemplate to send a Get request to a dummy server created by MockMvcBuilders. However I got an error:

> I/O error on GET request for `"http://localhost:8080/test"`:Connection refused:

(In the function testAccess(), url is `"http://localhost:8080/test"`). My code is as below:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@IntegrationTest("server.port=8080")
public class MyTest {

    private MockMvc mockMvc = null;

    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext context;

    @Value("${server.port}")
    private int port;

    @Autowired
    private MyController myController;

    @Before
    public void setUp(){

        mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(context)
            .build();
    }

    @Test
    public void testAccess() throws Exception{

        RestTemplate restTemplate=new RestTemplate();
        String url="http://localhost:8080/test";
        try{
            ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.GET, null, String.class);
        }
        catch(ResourceAccessException ex){
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());

        }
    }

    @Controller
    public static class MyController {

        @RequestMapping(value = "/test", method = RequestMethod.GET)
        public @ResponseBody String access() {
            return "OK";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The way I've done it is this:
First, you create a mock server from the actual RestTemplate you are using in your application

```
@Before
public void setup() throws Exception {
    mockServer = MockRestServiceServer.createServer(myService.restTemplate);
}
```

Then you define how that request is going to work:

```
    mockServer.expect(requestTo("http://localhost:8080/myrestapi"))
            .andExpect(method(HttpMethod.POST))
            .andRespond(withSuccess("{ success: true }", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
```

And last you call the method in your application that will trigger a call to that url with that RestTemplate:

```
@Test
public void testThis() throws Exception {
    myService.somethingThatCallsMyRestApi(parameters);
}
```

That will make your tests work as if there was a server up and running to process requests.
Using this in your example makes no sense, cause you would be testing that you build your test correctly and nothing else from the actual application.

The problem with this is that you cannot test dynamic responses. I mean, in my case the method I'm calling generates different data every time you call it and then sends it to the mockServer and then validates that the response matches in some very specific way. I haven't found a solution yet, but if the data you are going to send and receive is previously known, which would be in most cases, you'll have no problem using this.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you defining a controller in your Test class and then trying to test it ? It doesn't feel logical to try to test something that is defined within the test it self.

Rather you would want to test a controller defined somewhere outside your tests, an actual controller that is used within your application.

Let's say MyController is defined as an actual controller then you could use the mockMvc object you created to test it.

mockMvc.perform(get('/test'))
       .andExpect(status().isOk())

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I know mockMvc.perform works fine. But in my actual codes I use resttemplate. This is why I ask this question.